# A new Equation of a Straight Line

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, geometry

A new straight line equation?

$\frac{(y-y_2)}{(y-y_1)}=\frac{(x-x_2)}{(x-x_1)}$ is also a straight line equation?

Comment: Do you **really and honestly** think you could have possibly discovered a "new equation" of such a simple, basic and elementary object as a straight line in such a simple, basic and elementary subject as analytic geometry? And if you do: have you alreayd developed your "new equation" and cehck what you actually get?

Comment: this is called 2 point form.

Comment: The top comment here is condescending and makes me sad.

Comment: Joanpemo is quite the critic. We need people like him. NEED! I say. Because without them there wouldn't be the colour, black! lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph will be straight when your slope is constant.

The slope is given by $\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$ with $y_1$, $y_2$, $x_1$, $x_2$ being coordinates at two points.

In a straight line the slope is a constant.

So $\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{y_3-y_4}{x_3-x_4}$

So let's consider $3$ points. The slope between these should be same as they make a straight line.

So, $\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}$.

So, $\frac{y-y_2}{y-y_1} =\frac{x-x_2}{x-x_1}$.

So, I suppose this is not a new equation.

Answer (score 0):

Two point form st. line equation,

$(y-y_{1})=\frac{y_{1}-y_{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}}(x-x_{1})$

Or,

$ (y-y_{2})=\frac{y_{1}-y_{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}}(x-x_{2})$

Divide these two and we get ur new equation.

So, basically what's the point in remembering a equation of **lesser data** when we can easily remember the better one!!!